# flask sqlalchemy multiple foreign keys in relationship

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Hi I'm using flask and sqlalchemy, I'm trying to get the matches relationship in Team to get all matches whether or not it is *team1* or *team2* (so what i want is to be able to get all matches for given team through the matches attribute regardless if it is *team1* or *team2* in the `Match` table), I get the error:

sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Team.matches

There are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables. Specify the `foreign_keys` argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

```
class Match(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  map = db.Column(db.String(80), index=True)
  date = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True)
  agreed = db.Column(db.Boolean)
  done = db.Column(db.Boolean)
  ladder_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ladder.id'))
  team1_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('team.id'))
  team2_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('team.id'))
  team1_rounds = db.Column(db.Integer)
  team2_rounds = db.Column(db.Integer)
  team1_accepted_score = db.Column(db.Boolean)
  team2_accepted_score = db.Column(db.Boolean)
  points = db.Column(db.Integer)

  team1 = db.relationship('Team', foreign_keys='Match.team1_id')
  team2 = db.relationship('Team', foreign_keys='Match.team2_id')

class Team(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(80), index=True)
  tag = db.Column(db.String(20), index=True, unique=True)
  captain_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
  captain = db.relationship('User', uselist=False,
               foreign_keys='Team.captain_id')
  members = db.relationship('User', backref='team',
                foreign_keys='User.team_id', lazy='dynamic')
  matches = db.relationship('Match',
                 foreign_keys='[Match.team1_id, Match.team2_id]', lazy='dynamic')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got help from the guys on #sqlalchemy irc so i was going with the wrong approach I've now set up a relationship with a primaryjoin instead:

```
matches = db.relationship('Match', primaryjoin="or_(Team.id==Match.team1_id, Team.id==Match.team2_id)", lazy='dynamic')
```